# IPhone UIButton doesn't respond in a UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, uibutton

I'm an iPhone dev newbie, and I'm having a problem slightly similar to a few posts I read around here, but none of them seemed to help.

I have created a `UIScrollView`, with a `UIView` as its content (a subview). During runtime, the `UIView` is populated with labels and buttons. Everything looks fine, scrolling works perfectly, but the `UIButtons` never fire when pressed, no matter what I do. I've tried many combinations of properties suggested here, to the best of my understanding, but still nothing worked. I'm afraid I might have misunderstood something about the mechanism.

I should mention that everything is done in code (no IB).

Any suggestions?

Comment: You might want to update your question with a minimal code example. (Otherwise, we'll just be second-guessing what you'd done.) :-)

Comment: Do the buttons turn blue when poked?

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Apparently the question is not that interesting. The problem was that I only set the frame and content size of the scroll view, and also the frames of the labels and buttons I put inside the UIView. However, I did not set the frame of the UIView (subview of scrollview, parent of buttons etc.) at all. Surprisingly, this didn't stop it from showing and scrolling correctly, but did suppress the button clicks. [I discovered this when trying to create the minimal code reproducing the problem, thanks to middaparka's tip :) ]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My bug (written in the comments of my question) was not setting the frame of the contentview  that was the parent of all buttons. The result was strange - I could see the button subviews (which was why it took me a while to find the bug) but could not click on them. oops!

Answer (score 2):

This also may happen, when your custom `UIView` `userInteractionEnabled` is *NO* (default is *NO*).

Answer (score 0):

try `[btn becomeFirstResponder];`