# UIButton does not respond with UIScrollview Paging

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview, uibutton

I am running into a problem with the uiscrollview.  When I have it as a regular scroll view all the UIButtons work as expected.  When I add paging to it the buttons no longer respond.  I have a top edge sticking out and they do accept the press from there.  They are definitely behind the scroll view but they will scroll on and off the page when it is moved like I want them to.  I have read a lot of different responses but most will not provide the answer unless you use gesture controllers.  I am attaching the piece of code that creates the paging.  can you let me know what I might be missing?

```
-(void)scollPagingSetup:(float)frameSize {
float numberOfPages;
int maxheight;

[self.view setPagingEnabled:YES];
[self.view setBounces:YES];

UIView *first = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
[self.view addSubview:first];


maxheight = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;
numberOfPages = ceil(frameSize/maxheight);
for (int i = 1; i < numberOfPages; i++) {
    CGRect frame;
    frame.origin.x = 0;
    frame.origin.y = self.view.frame.size.height * i;
    frame.size = self.view.frame.size;

    UIView *subview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    [self.view addSubview:subview];

}

self.view.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height *numberOfPages);
}
```

Thank you in advance for taking a look.  I found something that would answer this problem but I was unable to grasp what the real solutions was to the problem.  here is the link to that question:

[IPhone UIButton doesn't respond in a UIScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4776768/2108963)

Comment: From what I read in the other question try changing the last line of code (right before the last "}") in your code to this: `self.view.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.height, first.view.frame.size.width);`

Comment: ^Also, in your code width and height were switched? Is that on purpose (i.e. something to do with landscape mode?) It is the common practice that height comes first then width... but I guess it doesn't matter so long that you get the desired result in the end, just wanted to make sure it wasn't a mistake 0:)

Comment: yes it is desired I am scrolling top to bottom as opposed to left and right.

Comment: Thank you this was most of the way to the answer and a little bit of fiddling and here is the final.  It was exactly in that line of code.      self.view.contentSize = CGSizeMake(first.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width*numberOfPages);

Comment: glad that was the solution, I will put it in the answer section below so that you can mark that as the solution for future users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the content size is not set properly so the "clickable area" (content area's size) is also not set... on your last line of code (line before the last "}") you are setting the scrollView's contentSize's frame to itself which will just be 0... try this instead (I use "first" (the nested view) instead of "self" (the scroll-view itself).

```
self.view.contentSize = CGSizeMake(firstframe.origin.x, (firstframe.origin.y - 20) * numberOfPages);
```

Note from question-poster on edited answer:

*I made a change to the answer. After I worked with the app some more i was not scrolling fully. I made the change to reflect what I did to fix this and cause a full page scroll. the -20 offset was needed due to the offset of the uiscrollview. This offset can be seen in interface builder.*